# (React Native) - Pass parameter in <FlatList renderItem>

Tags: javascript, react-native, parameters, react-props, flatlist

My FlatList looks like this:

```
<FlatList
   style={styles.scrollView}
   data={data}
   keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id} 
   renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
/>
```

Item looks like this:

```
const Item = ({ item }) => {
   ...
}
```

I want to pass a parameter (let's say I call it "myParam") to "Item" from FlatList renderItem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<FlatList
   style={styles.scrollView}
   data={data}
   keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id} 
   renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} myParam ={data}/>}
/>


const Item = ({ item, myParam }) => {
  ...
}
```